# In Geometry Nodes how can I transform an object proportionally with another object that's being controlled by an integer value?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector

I'm attempting to build a modular airplane hangar. In my current setup I have the hangar model split into the following 3 parts using vertex groups.

1. The front end
2. The hangar walls
3. The back end

The hangar walls depth is controlled by a mesh line which the model is then instanced on.
When I change the "Count" value, I want the back end of the model that I have separated to translate to where it should be: the very end of the instanced hangar walls model.

[image]

The model is 10 units long on the Y axis. I thought connecting the integer value and multiplying by 10 would work but I quickly realized I'm bad at math.

[image]

Is there any vector math wizardry I can do to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You are plugging an Integer output into a Vector input. Use a Math Multiply node instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AndréZmuda had one piece of the puzzle. I needed to use a math multiply instead of a Vector math multiply. In addition, I needed to 0 out the y position of the back wall. That way, it would be in the correct place when the integer is set to 1. Here's what my fix looks like:

[image]